# Hyperlinks with VLookup - Returns Error - Cannot Open Specified File

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

**The problem is:** I have named ranges of cells in `sheet3`. In `sheet2` I have created hyperlinks using range names so once you click in any of the links it takes you direct to the related range in `sheet3`.

In `sheet1` I have a table in which  column `K` is a droplist, in column `L` I entered this formula:

```
=HYPERLINK(VLOOKUP(K3,Sheet2!B48:C92,2,0))
```

which return the hyperlink matching to the selected value in column `K` the result returned is exactly the hyperlink in the *sheet2* but whenever I click any of these hyperlink results an error message pop up saying: **Cannot open the specified file**.

Even all the links in `Sheet2` is working fine and it take me direct to the linked range in `Sheet3`.

Do I need to insert a macro code to make the Vlookup-Hyperlinks results working and take me to the targeted range in `Sheet3` and whats the that code?

Answer (score 1):

If `=VLOOKUP(K3,Sheet2!B48:C92,2,0)` returns the *name* which is the target range of the hyperlink which is working in Sheet2, then the following should work in a HYPERLINK function:

```
=HYPERLINK("#"&VLOOKUP(K3,Sheet2!B48:C92,2,0))
```

The correct syntax would be:

```
=HYPERLINK("[NameOfTheWorkbook]"&VLOOKUP(K3,Sheet2!B48:C92,2,0))
```

according to : http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/hyperlink-function-HP010342583.aspx.

But the above syntax will also work. There the # works as a shortcut for "ThisWorkbook".

Greetings

Axel

Comment: Moving [NAA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49360907/6375113) to comment; The above should be: `=HYPERLINK("#'"&VLOOKUP(K3,Sheet2!B48:C92,2,0))`. You forgot ' after # .

Comment: @Bugs: No, my formula is correct. The question was about creating hyperlinks to **named ranges** and named ranges cannot contain spaces. The single quotes would only make sense if hyperlink to sheet names would be needed and the `VLOOKUP`would return those sheet names. But then it would must be `=HYPERLINK("#'"&VLOOKUP(K5,Sheet3!A:A,1,0)&"'!F5")` for example. So the single opening single qoute in `#'` would be useless at all.

Comment: Just to be clear. I'm not disputing your answer, just moving the NAA to a comment. However it's good you've replied as that might clear up any other confusions. Thank you.